# Adding new line in middle of echo inside exec in php

Tags: php, email, exec, echo, newline

Here is my exec command for sending email to users. I want to reformat the body of the mail by adding a newline after each App, config and counter type.

Here is the code that works but outputs everything in one line:

```
exec('echo "Please find attached the query result for:  App: '.$varApp.'  Config: '.$varConfig.' Counter Type: '.$varCtrType.'  Thanks!" | /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a '.$output[8].' '.$varEmail.'  2>&1', $output2 );
```

Here is the output from that command in the user email body:

```
Please find attached the query result for:  App: ABCDEF Config: GHIJK   
Counter Type: LMNOP <br> Thanks!
```

I have tried using 
 and /r/n without any luck. I also tried different combinations of adding quotes and /.

The code that doesn't give any desired output.

```
exec('echo "Please find attached the query result for:'<br>'  App: '.$varApp.' '<br>' Config: '.$varConfig.' <br> Counter Type: '.$varCtrType.' <br> Thanks!" | /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a '.$output[8].' '.$varEmail.'  2>&1', $output2 )
```

OR

```
exec('echo "Please find attached the query result for:/r/n  App: '.$varApp.' /r/n Config: '.$varConfig.' <br> Counter Type: '.$varCtrType.' <br> Thanks!" | /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a '.$output[8].' '.$varEmail.'  2>&1', $output2 );
```

I think I don't know how to add breaks/newline in middle of this echo statement.
Any guidance here is deeply appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to use `\n` or `PHP_EOL`?

Comment: Why are you using `exec()` to send mail? PHP has a built-in `mail()` function, and there are also libraries like `PHPMailer`

Comment: I don't have sudo access to download scripts required for PHPmailer and sending attchments using mail() is very difficult. So, I was just trying out something from command line and it worked. Decided to extend it to my php :) I do know that most people will object to a kind of non-standard approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `printf` command instead of `echo`, it processes escape sequences in the format string.

Also, the escape sequence for newline is `\n`, not `/n`. You don't need `\r` at all.

```
exec('printf "Please find attached the query result for:\n  App: %s \n Config: %s \n Counter Type: %s \n Thanks!" "' . $varApp . '" "' . $varConfig . '" "' . $varCtrType . '"| /bin/mail -s "Testing" -a '.$output[8].' '.$varEmail.'  2>&1', $output2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I think there is a missing single quote before $varctrtype. However, that didnt fix the problem.

Comment: You're right. There was also an extra single quote before `|`. This is why I don't usually use variable concatenation, I do substitution inside double quotes.

Comment: Thanks! The problem now is that all the variable values ($varApp,$varConfig, $varCtrType) are printed in same line instead of corresponding locations. i.e App Name: all three variables values printed here. Although, App name, Configuration and counter type are in separate line.

Comment: Are you sure you copied all the quotes properly? I just tested it and I think it should work correctly.

Comment: Fixed it by replacing %s with variables. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: as an extension of the problem in hand. Do you also happen to know if I can do text formatting within this statement e.g making words bold or changing size and color.

Comment: You'll need to send HTML email to do that.